# Powershell command alternative to Telnet for managing router

Tags: powershell, command, telnet, router

1. I need to reboot my wireless router (ZyXEL P-660HN-T1A) at a scheduled time (using task scheduler in Windows 7).
2. The live and manual **telnet** command-line version to the task above is this:

   ```
   telnet 192.168.1.1
   password: **********
   sys reboot
   exit
   ```
3. Now I want alternatively to use **Powershell** to automate and script (using probably TcpClient) the above commands and then run that script at the required time with Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Something to start with here http://poshcode.org/2683 maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I found a proper script here: https://github.com/chrisdee/Scripts/blob/master/PowerShell/Working/telnet/PowerShellTelnetRemoteSession.ps1

```
## PowerShell: Script To Telnet To Remote Hosts And Run Commands Against Them With Output To A File ##
## Overview: Useful for Telnet connections to Cisco Switches and other devices. Can add additional command strings
## Usage Examples: Add your environment specific details into the parameters below, or include when calling the script:
## ./PowerShellTelnetRemoteSession.ps1 "127.0.0.1" "23" "admin" "password" "term len 0" "en" "enablepassword" "show interface"
param(
    [string] $remoteHost = "",
    [int] $port = 23,
    [string] $username = "",
    [string] $password = "",
    [string] $termlength = "term len 0", #Useful for older consoles that have line display limitations
    [string] $enable = "en", #Useful for appliances like Cisco switches that have an 'enable' command mode
    [string] $enablepassword = "",
    [string] $command1 = "show interface", #You can add additional commands below here with additonal strings if you want
    [int] $commandDelay = 1000
)

[string] $output = ""

## Read output from a remote host
function GetOutput
{
    ## Create a buffer to receive the response
    $buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024
    $encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding
    $outputBuffer = ""
    $foundMore = $false

    ## Read all the data available from the stream, writing it to the
    ## output buffer when done.
    do
    {
        ## Allow data to buffer for a bit
        start-sleep -m 1000

        ## Read what data is available
        $foundmore = $false

        $stream.ReadTimeout = 1000
        do
        {
            try
            {
                $read = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)
                if($read -gt 0)
                {
                    $foundmore = $true
                    $outputBuffer += ($encoding.GetString($buffer, 0, $read))
                }
            } catch { $foundMore = $false; $read = 0 }
        } while($read -gt 0)
    } while($foundmore)

    $outputBuffer
}

function Main
{
    ## Open the socket, and connect to the computer on the specified port
    write-host "Connecting to $remoteHost on port $port"
    trap { Write-Error "Could not connect to remote computer: $_"; exit }
    $socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($remoteHost, $port)
    write-host "Connected. Press ^D followed by [ENTER] to exit.`n"
    $stream = $socket.GetStream()
    $writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream

    ## Receive the output that has buffered so far
    $SCRIPT:output += GetOutput
    $writer.WriteLine($username)
    $writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    $writer.WriteLine($password)
    $writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    $writer.WriteLine($termlength)
    $writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    $writer.WriteLine($enable)
    $writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    $writer.WriteLine($enablepassword)
    $writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    $writer.WriteLine($command1) #Add additional entries below here for additional 'strings' you created above
    $writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -m $commandDelay
    $SCRIPT:output += GetOutput

    ## Close the streams
    $writer.Close()
    $stream.Close()
    $output | Out-File ("C:\BoxBuild\$remoteHost.txt") #Change this to suit your environment
}
. Main
```

You could easily modify the value of $command1 variable to output your required commands.
I also removed the $username input and changed the values of $password, $remoteHost, $port to the required ones.

For the part of scheduling the task, after saving the edited script mentioned above, I ran it through a command like the following with the maximum privileges from a Task Scheduler event in windows:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\PowerShellTelnetRemoteSession.ps1"
```

"-executionpolicy bypass" is so to bypass powershell security for unsigned scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cisco UCS it has a module for PS management of devices. Not very familiar with it, I just know it exists.

http://blogs.cisco.com/tag/powershell/

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/sw/msft_tools/powertools/ucs_powertool_book/ucs_pwrtool_bkl1.pdf

This guy talks about about some other options too..

http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/james/fun-with-powershell-plink-cisco-ios-and-powershell/